# display error message under payment method if "COD " is not available

Tags: payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

i am using this following code to restrict the "cash on delivery" payment method based on pin code.

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cashondelivery.php
```

Please check code [here](http://pastebin.com/kY1tsuZB)

now if cash on delivery payment method is not visible means i want to display "cod is not available" under

payment method.

please help me to find solution.

Comment: please try  if (!in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)) {
throw new Mage_Core_Exception(Mage::helper('payment')->__('Code is not avaliable.'));

     return false;
        }

Comment: i did what you told, check here once : pastebin.com/EX6q7zSG but i am getting error : "Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons". please see when u r free.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You referral link can only remove the code from payment list at check payment step.If you set error message at session `(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('payment')->__('Code is not avaliable.')))`  on function `isAvaliable`  it can be shown on next step.

According my concept it will be `good idea to do something at methods.phtml where all payment method has been listing` during the checkout.

```
<?php
$isCodeAvalibale=0;
    foreach ($this->getMethods() as $_method):
        $_code = $_method->getCode();
    if($_code =='cashondelivery'):
    $isCodeAvalibale=1;
    endif;
    endforeach;
if($isCodeAvalibale==0):
echo Mage::helper('payment')->__('Code is not avaliable.'));
endif;
?>
```

Comment: can you please tell in which file , i have to add this code : "(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('payment')->__('Code is not avaliable.')))"

Comment: i followed your code here :

app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml. 

methods.phtml = > http://pastebin.com/B8XbJY4m

but after "shipping information" it's redirecting to "checkout " page.

but i did't got where to use this code : 

(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('payment')->__('Code is not avaliable.')))

Comment: Please use my code. Please don't use session.as I mentioned

Comment: i did't used that session, i used only your code here : http://pastebin.com/B8XbJY4m 

please check the above code file....

Comment: please open template hint.. check the file at checkout payment step

Comment: i enabled it...... please check here : http://demo2.kidsdial.com/index.php/checkout/cart/

Comment: it is not possiable to check myself. i was give idea.please do yourself...

Comment: okay boss, i will try it....